# How can use querybuilder with Symfony formbuilder to join two entities?

Tags: php, symfony, join, query-builder, formbuilder

```
$options['class'] = 'App\\Entity\\Data';
$options['attr'] = array('class' => 'form-control select2');
$options['query_builder'] = function (EntityRepository $er) use ($fieldId,$documentId) {
    return $er->createQueryBuilder('data')
        ->leftJoin('data.documents', 'dd')
        ->andWhere('dd.pages = :id')
        ->andWhere('dd.uuid = data.document_id')
        ->andWhere('data.field = :field')
        ->setParameter(':id', 16)
        ->setParameter(':field', 35)
     ;
};
$options['choice_label'] = 'content';
```

The error message:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 127 near 'field = :fie': Error: Class
> App\Entity\Data has no field or association named field

Comment: Is `data.field` a valid mapped field? also check the parameter setters, it's `->setParameter('id', 16)` without `:`, same for field parameter.

Comment: I'd also say, that your error message doesn't match your code.

Comment: @yceruto Thank you, this solved the problem! Only problem now is, that I do not have any data in my select box `<select> </select>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the following in your class?

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Data
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="field")
     */
    private $field;
}
```

Normally that would be enough for doctrine to resolve that error

- And as @yceruto says in the comments

It is

```
// This is right
->setParameter('field', 22)
```

Instead of

```
// This is wrong
->setParameter(':field', ...)
```

Comment: Thank you, the error is gone now. But the select box is now empty `<select>
</select>`

Comment: I don't think this line is necessary either because doctrine handles that when you mapping is correct: ->andWhere('dd.uuid = data.document_id')